# Android activity launch time from logcat vs log in code

Tags: android, performance, logcat

First of all, I'm using two ways of measuring activity launch time.
The first one is using the following command `adb logcat -b events -d | grep am_activity_launch_time` where the second from the last is represents the launch time.

```
11-02 17:14:39.710   608   626 I am_activity_launch_time [0,146177546,com.example.audiorecorder/.MainActivity,322,322]
```

Anyway, if use in code `Log.i(appName, start)` right in the beginning of `onCreate` and in the end of `onResume()` the elapsed time is around 50ms (which seems pretty impossible), comparing to 322ms from the logcat.

Any ideas of this discrepancy being so big?

I need to achieve a right measurement value using `Log.i()` in order to calculate the overhead of the same application (activity) using a binder service that I developed.

Thanks!